# Help requested to install a driver for a TP-link TL-WN 823N wireless adapter

Tags: drivers, usb

I am attempting to install a driver for a TP-link TL-WN 823N wireless adapter. I have already posted on this forum, but although I’ve made some progress, I still haven't been successful in getting the wireless set-up to work.     I am not very au fait with Ubuntu, and certainly very new to the process of installing drivers.
I followed the suggestions on this forum to use Pilot6’s PPA. However I’m still unable to link to the router for my home PC or the router we use in a small shop I manage.

The code I used as per Pilot6 was:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

This seemed to work OK – no errors. However I still can’t access the internet via the dongle. The dongle does work on my daughter’s PC which runs on Windows.

When I run nmcli dev on my home PC I get the following:

```
DEVICE /                             TYPE   /      STATE          
enx98ded01807c2        /       wifi       /      disconnected  
eth0                /                      ethernet  /    unavailable  
lo                          /                loopback  /  unmanaged
```

When I type in lsusb, again on my home PC,  I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver  
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:5511 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet F300 series  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:0b0c Hewlett-Packard Wireless Keyboard and Optical Mouse  Receiver  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: No I didn't, because I didn't know I had to, and I don't know how either. Are you able to help with that?  Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Thanks for that Pilot6, but I have tried 2 of the ways now (of disabling Secure Boot) and neither have worked. When I went the mokutil route, I entered :  sudo mokutil --disable-validation and got back 
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Comment: And when I followed the method in the wiki I got the following:   sudo: update-secureboot-policy: command not found

Comment: It is better to switch it off from BIOS. But maybe you do not have UEFI.

Comment: Oh dear!!  What is UEFI?  I tried doing ESC when the PC was restarting, but it didn't give me a menu I recognised.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your help so far - I have tried hitting esc, F2, F12, del during the boot-up process; using esc I get one screen which just gives me 3 boot options, but no option to disable Secure Boot; using F12 eventually takes me into what looks like a grub screen, but I have no idea what I'm doing there. Should I be starting a new question about how to get into BIOS?

Comment: What is your BIOS and how to get there is off-topic. You need to look into your computer's manual.

Comment: @Pilot6  Yes, I thought so - I will have to ask the chap who installed Ubuntu on this PC for me. Thanks again for your help so far. At least I've learned more about using the Ask Ubuntu forums!!

Comment: I have got into what I think is BIOS, but I can find no option there to disable Secure Boot

Comment: Maybe it is not an UEFI.